# my go.Scatter text doesnt work but my figure does

Tags: plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I try to do some graphs with plotly.graph_object.

My figure works but not my text.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[5,15,15,5],
    
                            y=[0,0,niveau_coupon[1], niveau_coupon[0]],
                            
                            fill='toself',
                            fillcolor='grey',
                            line=dict(width=0),
                            showlegend=False,
                            mode='lines',  
                            hoverinfo ='none',
                            text=["testttttttttttt"],
                  textposition='top right',
                  textfont=dict(color='white'),
))
```

Thanks for yours answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key change `mode="lines+text"` Also changed

- position to make it visible
- list length 4 so each point has some text
- from comments you not you want text add middle of area.   This therefore means it is an annotation.  Provided example

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import math

fig = go.Figure()
niveau_coupon = [10, 20]

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[5, 15, 15, 5],
        y=[0, 0, niveau_coupon[1], niveau_coupon[0]],
        fill="toself",
        fillcolor="grey",
        line=dict(width=0),
        showlegend=False,
        mode="lines+text",
        hoverinfo="none",
        text=["testttttttttttt"] * 4,  # one for each point..
        textposition="top center",  # changed to make it visible on right
        textfont=dict(color="white"),
    )
)

fig.add_annotation(
    x=sum(fig.data[0].x) / len(fig.data[0].x),
    y=sum(fig.data[0].y) / len(fig.data[0].y),
    text="test",
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(color="white")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah it works thanks! But i would like to put one "testttt" between the 4 points. On the center, Is there a way? Really thank you for your answer!

Comment: updated - you are really talking about an annotation rather than text associated with a point